# How to Store each value of i in cells when i is a decimal?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I store each value of `i` through the loop in cells when `i` is decimal?

```
t=0.4
n=0.05 (user input)

For i = 0 To t Step n
Ab = 1042 * i ^ 4 + 1020 * i ^ 3 - 345.63 * i ^ 3 + 52.99 * i
Debug.Print i

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean sth like this

```
t = 0.4
n = 0.05    '(user input)
j = 1
For i = 0 To t Step n
    Ab = 1042 * i ^ 4 + 1020 * i ^ 3 - 345.63 * i ^ 3 + 52.99 * i
    Debug.Print i
    Cells(j, 1).Value2 = i
    Cells(j, 2).Value2 = ab
    j = j + 1
Next
```